# How to separate between 2 straight sends?

Tags: java, sockets, stream, nio

I'm using java NIO, and I want to send the player a message and then send  another message immediately.

So I'm just sending 2 messages in a row:

```
server.send("message 1");
server.send("message 2");
```

The client receives the message:

```
client.read(buffer)
```

So the buffer looks like this:

```
message1+message2
```

I want the client to see it as 2 messages,
the problem is that I write to the stream twice in a row and the client reads the stream all at once, and gets all the data(2 messages) like it is one message.

Is there a way to check if the stream is empty, and only when it's empty, to write the second message?

Comment: Delimit your messages, for example with a newline character, then read line by line.

Comment: yea but when i use the method "socketchannel.read" it reads me all the stream? how can i limit it?

Comment: Send a header before each message containing the number of bytes in the message.

Comment: If you use TCP, it´s up to you to take care of structuring the stream into messages.If you use UDP, it´s up to you to take care of message duplication / miss / order. With any protocol there´s work to be done, both are just (relatively low level) infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

Your question actually requires a lot of answers. As a starting point, you should start reading documentation about network protocols and Java sockets programming. Protocols were invented exactly to address the issue you are facing. The simplest protocol you need at this point is a Framing protocol.

In order for two (or more) parties to understand each other, you have to define a basic shared "language" so that they can extract and interpret actual messages from a continuous or pseudo-continuous stream of information.

In brief, the classic parts needed to implement communication between remote parties are typically:

- the transmitter, or writer (typically a socket to write to)
- the receiver, or reader (typically a socket to read from - often buffered)
- the framer (relative to your Framing protocol): it frames messages from the stream.
- the codec(s) (an encoder + a decoder): they decode framed messages or encode new message as bytes to be send or written to the stream.
- then a bunch of interpreters and handlers for each kind of message
- ultimately business logic happens in the handlers or by the components that listen for messages, commands, events triggered or shared by the handlers.

To strictly answer your question, you should use a framing protocol if you are using TCP communication which would add a fixed-length message-length header to your messages. Eg. the first 2 bytes are the length of the message, followed by the message. If you use UDP you less likely need a framer but other mechanisms.

Please clarify your needs if needed, but first read the wide litterature available on network protocols: starting with TCP/UDP and their differences, the concepts of headers, payload, contents, delimiters and framing, buffers, integrity, handshakes, graceful close of stream, keep-alives, codecs, ...